# How can I run a script immediately after connecting via SSH?

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, tmux

*I started to ask this question but answered it while I had it open. I'm going to post this question, follow it up with my solution and leave it open to other potential solutions.*

**`<`backstory`>`**

I'm a tmux and vim user. I like remote vim work as I don't have to worry about Ubuntu development machines kirking out when a flash movie gives me a kernel panic. Running tmux means that open files are waiting for me after I reboot and I can carry on from where I left off. I've had problems with vim running in a tmux session when I connect like so:

```
ssh example.com -t 'tmux attach'
```

UTF-8 issues crop up that don't crop up when shelling in normally and just attaching to a tmux session manually.

**`<`/backstory`>`**

So I want a reusable method of starting something on ssh login, that doesn't affect any of the other things I have configured in my `.zshrc` (or your `.bashrc` if you still use bash) that may be required for my development environment, that doesn't appear when I'm occasionally working locally on the very said machine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you run `ssh example.com`, the ssh daemon starts a login shell for you, and the login shell reads your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zprofile` or `~/.login` depending on your login shell). When you specify a command to run remotely (with or without `-t`), the ssh daemon starts an ordinary shell, so your `.profile` is not read. Remedy:

```
ssh example.com -t '. /etc/profile; . ~/.profile; tmux attach'
```

Most ssh daemons are configured to refuse transmitting environment variables except for `LC_*`. If the ssh daemon on `example.com` allows it, you can abuse a custom `LC_*` variable to start tmux automatically — put this in your `~/.profile`:

```
if [ -n "$LC_tmux_session" ] && tmux has -t "$LC_tmux_session"; then
  exec tmux attach -t "$LC_tmux_session"
elif [ -n "${LC_tmux_session+1}" ] && tmux has; then
  exec tmux attach
fi
```

then log in with `LC_tmux_session= ssh example.com` or `LC_tmux_session=session_name ssh example.com`.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/207200/how-can-i-set-environment-variables-for-a-remote-rsync-process/207262#207262) has more information about passing environment variables over ssh.

Comment: The reason I'm not using `ssh example.com -t 'tmux attach'` isn't because it has problems loading my environment but because I've had issues with UTF-8 character display; this issue doesn't exist when connecting in the conventional manner. This is why this question is about running scripts immediately after connecting over SSH.

Comment: I love your solution though. Elegant

Comment: @connrs: Do you have issues with UTF-8 even when you run your `.profile`? I assumed the issue was due to incorrectly set locales on the target machine, which your `/etc/profile` or `.profile` fixed. The locale issue is probably fixable with more information.

Comment: I wanted to get back to the office to test this. You are totally correct, sourcing the /etc/profile does trigger proper behaviour. You've now actually solved the problem that motivated me to ask this more generic question

Answer (score 6):

*I previously advised setting `PermitUserEnvironment yes` and adding an environment variable in your `~/.ssh/environment` until [Eli Heady](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1323/eli-heady) chipped in with a better suggestion in the comments below.*

Open your `.zlogin` (bash: `.bash_profile` etc.) and put the following:

```
if [[ "$SSH_CONNECTION" != "" && "$MY_SSH_CONNECTION" != "yes" ]]; then
    while true; do
        echo -n "Do you want to attach to a tmux session? [y/n]"
        read yn
        case $yn in
            [Yy]* ) MY_SSH_CONNECTION="yes" tmux attach; break;;
            [Nn]* ) break;;
            * ) echo "Please answer y/n";;
        esac
    done
fi
```

Inspiration taken from: [How do I prompt for input in a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script)

*Note that I've used the `.zlogin` file but you could use your `.zshrc` file but I like to keep my dotfiles tidy and it separates it so I can use it on other machines.*

Replace the question with something appropriate for yourself and replace `MY_SSH_CONNECTION="yes" tmux attach` with whatever you wish to run at that point.

Note how the script sets `MY_SSH_CONNECTION="yes"` before `tmux attach` to pass it through to tmux as it also will be opening a shell that will access the very same script above and will prevent any recursion.

Comment: Use of PermitUserEnvironment will not be possible in some environments due to the potential security implications. SSH sets the $SSH_CONNECTION variable, which can be used in place of your $SSH_LOGIN in your .zlogin, obviating the need to use ~/.ssh/environment. Something like `if [[ "$SSH_CONNECTION" != "" ]]` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Myself, I add this to my .bash_profile files:

```
if [ -z "$STY" ]; then
    reattach() { exec screen -A -D -RR ${1:+"$@"} ; }
fi
if [ -t 0 ]; then
    screen -wipe
    echo 'starting screen... (type Ctrl-C to abort)'
    sleep 5 && reattach
fi
```

This gives me some time to abort reattaching to or creating a screen session. It won't work on 'ssh system command' formats (which does not call ~/.*profile). A shell function is set up to reattach if I abort.

Comment: Great! I managed to f* this up by putting in bashrc instead, and then in each new screen window - when changing to .profile it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider running

```
ssh remotehost -t screen -DR
```

and run your terminal session there. You can then detach (`^A^D`) and reattach later (from a different client as well). It will make the problem with non-interactive initialization go away as screen keeps full interactive terminal sessions (optionally logon shells as well, `man screen`(1) or `^A?`)

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I'm using tmux rather than GNU screen to manage my sessions. And when loaded with `-t 'tmux attach'` I have issues with vim that aren't present normally. This is why the real question is about running scripts on ssh connect rather than screen/session management. Apologies for not being clearer in my question

Comment: So sorry, you mentioned tmux but it didn't mean anything to me. Thanks for mentioning a new tool though!

Answer (score 0):

To speak to the UTF-8 issues specifically, if you add

```
SendEnv LANG
```

And `$LANG` is set to something like `en_US.UTF-8` on the local end and your sshd on the remote end permits the `SendEnv` directive (with `AcceptEnv` in `sshd_config`), the tmux on the other end should honor it. I had this problem for a while and it was difficult to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to run every time you connect, you could simply add `tmux attach` to the bottom of your `~/.profile` on the remote machine.